# Can I use ssh config name when using Itamae

Tags: provisioning, itamae

I'm using Itamae with a command like this:

```
itamae ssh -u ironsand -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx cookbooks/user.rb
```

The ssh configuration are saved with a name `my_ssh_config`.
Can I use the ssh config name as a argument of `itamae ssh`?

### my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host my_ssh_config
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User ironsand
```

Comment: Do you mean using a host alias? ie. in your ssh config, do you have lines like: Host alias1 alias2; HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, and you want to use -h alias1 instead of -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?

Comment: yeah, host alias and user name also. Like when I connect server by `ssh my_ssh_config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of March 30, support for using ssh config hosts was merged into itamae's master branch:

https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/pull/115

So as long as you are using a recent copy of itamae, this functionality should be supported:

```
itamae ssh -h my_ssh_config cookbooks/user.rb
```

or

```
itamae ssh --host=my_ssh_config cookbooks/user.rb
```

You may also need to specify your key file on the command line using the `-i` option:

```
itamae ssh --host=my_ssh_config -i ~/.ssh/my_ssh_host.key cookbooks/user.rb
```

or with an `IdentityFile` stanza in your ssh config:

```
Host my_ssh_config
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User ironsand
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_ssh_host.key
```